# OrientDB Studio - Unable to login into database once logout

Tags: java, spring-mvc, maven-3, ioexception, orientdb

I have created a new **database** using **OrientDB Studio** named **SpringMVC_DB** with user credentials **root/root**. It is created successfully. Then I logged out from the OrientDB studio.

I wrote a **Java program** to create Vertices & Edges in the above DB. The **vertices** named **FS** & **ABC** & an **edge** in between them called **has customer** are created successfully.

Now, I want to view them in Graph mode so, **I shutdown the Jetty server & again login to OrientDB Studio**. It'll ask me to enter user credentials. I tried **root/root**, **admin/admin**, **root/pwd**. But, **none of them allow me access my database**. I also tried to drop this database from OrientDB Studio, but stuck on the same problem.

I have also **tried to reset password** from login into another DB (the default one, GratefulDeadConcerts) using below command, **password reset but, no success in login to SpringMVC_DB**.

```
update ouser set password = 'admin' where name = 'admin'
```

---

**FYI :** I am using following **dependency** in my application

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
    <artifactId>orientdb-graphdb</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

---

**OrientDB Console Output:** The output of the console shows some other process has locked the configuration file. But, there is no process accessing the OrientDB.

[image: Error login OrientDB Database]

---

**EDIT:**

Now I **restart** my PC & **starts only OrientDB** using **server.bat** file then console shows *SpringMVC_DB was not closed properly*. See below screenshot:

[image: Error login OrientDB after restarting PC]

**orientdb-server-config.xml:**

```
<users>
    <user name="root" password="root" resources="*"/>
    <user name="guest" password="guest" resources="connect,server.listDatabases,server.dblist"/>
</users>
```

---

**My question:**

1. Does the difference in dependency (2.0.5) & downloaded OrientDB community (2.0.M3) have any concern with the above mentioned problem ?
2. How can I get access to my DB (SpringMVC_DB) ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Go to this file `ODB_HOME/config/orientdb-server-config.xml`, see which is your root password and try to login.
But your problem seems to be another one. You have a process that locked the db and it's still alive. Once it dies (or you kill it), I believe you'll be able to login.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please have a look at edit I made.

Comment: I doesn't look good. I don't have any more ideas. If the info is crucial for you, open an issue and maybe someone from OrientDB team can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This issue has been resolved in `orientdb-community-2.0.5` release**. I have **verified** this by following the same procedure mentioned in question & I am able to access the OrientDB database.

Also have a look at [Orientdb issue I raised](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/3775)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have opened the same database using plocal with both console and server, or maybe 2 servers. Assure only 1 server is running.

Comment: No, there is only one instance of database opened at a time. When console is running, server is shutdown & vice versa. Do u check the error in second screenshot ? It shows **SpringMVC_DB was not closed properly**. I don't know how to resolve this error. I have tried to close database instance, but, I don't know at point it is good to open & close it in my application. Can u suggest on this ?